# How to call a proc from a particular sourced file if there are multiple sourced files with same proc names?

Tags: tcl

I am trying to write a wrapper tcl which sources multiple tcl files and these tcl files have some proc which have the same names in more than 1 file. How do I explicitly call for a proc from a particular file?

I searched stack overflow and I came across proc rename, but I am wondering if there is another solution. Perhaps cleaner.

Comment: Apologies for not putting an example. I am unable to post a sample code. It keeps saying I have some formatting error.

Comment: Try to post the code and someone will help you to format it.

Comment: The proper way to do it as I understand it is to use [namespaces](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/namespace.htm). Let's say the first file uses the namespace `a` and the second the namespace `b`, then you can call `proc`s from the first file using `::a::procname` and from the second file using `::b::procname`.

Comment: Using either namespaces or interpreters to separate things is the right way to go. Which one to use depends on exactly what you want: namespaces are (much!) lighter weight, and interpreters provide strong separation (nearly as strong as using a subprocess).

Answer (score 1):

It is kind of tricky, but you can go ahead with slave interpreters to distinguish between the files.

**add.tcl**

```
proc calculate {a b} {
        return [expr {$a+$b}]
}
```

**sub.tcl**

```
proc calculate {a b} {
        return [expr {$a-$b}]
}
```

**file_src_manager.tcl**

```
array set tclEngine {}
set files  {add.tcl sub.tcl}
foreach f $files {
  # Creating slave interpreter for each files.
  set tclEngine($f) [interp create]
  # Sourcing them in separate interpreter
  if {[catch {interp eval $tclEngine($f) "source $f"} issue]} {
    puts "Failed to source $f. Reason - $issue"
  }
}
# Calling add.tcl file's calculate method
puts [interp eval $tclEngine(add.tcl) "calculate 5 3"]
# Calling sub.tcl file's calculate method
puts [interp eval $tclEngine(sub.tcl) "calculate 5 3"]
```

**Output**

```
8
2
```

**Reference :** [interp](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/interp.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You can organise the `source`'ed procs in separate namespaces, e.g., by re-using the script names as namespace names:

### add.tcl

```
namespace eval ::[file tail [info script]] {
    proc calculate {a b} {
        return [expr {$a+$b}]
    }
    namespace export calculate
}
```

### sub.tcl

```
namespace eval ::[file tail [info script]] {
    proc calculate {a b} {
        return [expr {$a-$b}]
    }
    namespace export calculate
}
```

Then, in your main script, you may switch back and forth between the different proc pools e.g. using `[namespace import]`:

```
% source add.tcl
% source sub.tcl
% namespace import -force ::add.tcl::*
% calculate 5 3
8
% namespace import -force ::sub.tcl::*
% calculate 5 3
2
```

### Remarks

- [`[info script]`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/info.htm#M38) returns the currently sourced script file (is set by the `source` command behind the scenes).
- Makes sure to [`[namespace export]`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/namespace.htm#M12) the pooled procs. Otherwise, they won't become imported.
- Using the `-force` flag on [`namespace import`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/namespace.htm#M14) will silently replace equally named commands (procs) in the target namespace.
- Using namespaces over slave interpreters (as suggested by Dinesh) is a matter of consequences and your use case: Do the procs need to share some state (variables) or some resources (channels)? Should the procs be restricted to use only files within their `source` context? etc.
- You can certainly define your own variant of `source` that avoids the boilerplate in each and every `source`'ed script.

Comment: As pointed out by @Jerry, you can certainly always point explicitly to the pooled procs using the namespace qualifiers: `::add.tcl::calculate`, `::sub.tcl::calculate`, ...

Comment: The procs in my case are mutually exclusive but they do share the variables from the wrapper script. Does the interpreter work better in that case?

Comment: If they share the variables in the spirit of `global` or `upvar`, then the namespace approach is more adequate.